# Where is set shipping_description value in sales_flat_order table?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, orders

I need to set a new value for the `shipping_description` column of the `sales_flat_order` table.

I would like to know in which file I can define this value before the order is created in the database ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add an observer on the *'sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after'* event.

In your custom module, in config.xml add the following:

```
<config>
    ....
    <frontend>
            <events>                
                <sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after>
                    <observers>
                        <adjust_shipping_description>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>model_group/observer</class>
                            <method>adjustShippingDescription</method>
                        </adjust_shipping_description>
                    </observers>
                </sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after>
            </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

then add the Observer.php class in your module's Model folder with the following code:

```
    /**
     * Will set a new shipping description for the current quote
     *
     * @author Your Name <your_email@domain.com>
     * @event  sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after
     * @scope  frontend
     * @param  Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function adjustShippingCostsData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var $address Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address */
        $address = $observer->getQuoteAddress();

        $newDescription = 'test string';

        // reset description on shipping address
        $address->setShippingDescription($newDescription);       
    }
```

** **don't forget to correctly map** the observer class relative to your module in the config(the 'model_group' part) and also the php class name and location. Also, if you need this change to occur for both orders placed in frontend and admin panel, change the  tag to